# c# interface for basic database access (EF)

Tags: c#, database, interface

I usually create a static class for my database calls. I have never used interfaces before, so i would like to see a correct example of how this could be used in my case. Im using entity framework to fetch the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the operations such as Connect, Execute and related instructions you can use your interface, such a way i can always couple any DB to this interface. Ill show you one such example

```
      interface SqlInterface
    {
     void Connect();

    }

    public class SqlServer : SqlInterface
{
   public void Connect() {

 //Connection code related to SQl Server
}
}
```

Hope you got the point now? Or you were looking for some thing else?

Comment: Okay, what about methods that are for example checking if a user is online, returning usernames etc? Are interfaces not used for that?

Comment: if their implementation varies for each of the DB you wish to support today or tomorrow, then YES! You can push them to either abstract class or interfaces. And interfaces come in handy to publish it as a contract to accross teams or various other developers where in they can use it to write de-coupled code. Plus dependency injection possible to do unit testing.

Comment: Okay, and ill save the file as an interface named "IDatabaseSomething.." or just "DatabaseSOmething"?

Comment: Its a conding guidelines to always have interface names prefixed with I char, like ISomeInterface

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Repository design pattern, and Interfaces of this classes of Repositories for data base access look at this article,
[EF and Repository](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) and
[EF with Repository](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx)